# Gallery selected item background not persisting

Tags: android, gallery

I'm using gallery to display some images. I have used below adapter and gallery selector for gallery item selection.

ImageAdapter:

```
public class AddImgAdp extends BaseAdapter {

        private int[] galleryImages;

        public AddImgAdp(int[] images) {
            galleryImages = images;


        }

        public int getCount() {
            return galleryImages.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {

            final ImageView iv = new ImageView(ChooseLinerActivity.this);
            iv.setImageResource(galleryImages[position]);
            iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            iv.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            iv.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.galleryselector));


               iv.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

            return iv;

        }
    }
```

galleryselector:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item  android:state_selected="true" 
                        android:drawable="@drawable/large_button_sel2"/>
        <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

My problem is when I click or scroll through gallery it displays background, but when I click on another view which is under gallery view then the selection disappears.

Comment: Did you get the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you click another view which is under the gallery, your gallery was unfocused.of cause, views in your gallery were unselected.

Comment: Please write a comment for trivial answers.